# Namenode not starting

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I'm trying to setup a hadoop cluster. But the namenode isn't starting.
When i check the logs, it shows :

> 2016-10-19 05:23:10,140 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.
>
> NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name
>   at index 0: 192.168.100.101:9001
>           at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.setClientNamenodeAddress(NameNode.java:352)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:755)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:748)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1441)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1507)
>
> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme
>   name at index 0: 192.168.100.101:9001
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3012)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3028)
>           at java.net.URI.(URI.java:595)
>           at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
>           ... 5 more 2016-10-19 05:23:10,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1 2016-10-19
>   05:23:10,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
>
> SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>
> /************************************************************
>
> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at namenode1/192.168.100.101

I've checked the core-site.xml file and found no errors.

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>192.168.100.101:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
~
```

I've also tried deleting the temp folder, formatting the namenode and starting it again.

Comment: can you send the command which you tried to start namenode

Comment: hdfs namenode -format

and then 

hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Replace value of fs.default.name with `hdfs://192.168.100.101:9001`

2) Check your site.xml files, whether in value you have mistakenly added space in between

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!! It was the missing hdfs in the value.